# How to search in PHP using Drupal 7 Search API?

Tags: php, drupal

I can't seem to find a simple way to do a search. It seems "hook_search_execute" is if you want the search api to also search custom things in your own module. It doesn't actually allow me to do something like this:

```
$results = drupal_function_of_some_type("amazing things");
```

I just want a way to get the same search results the normal api would do if it was trying to get results. How do I plug into that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
$results = search_data('amazing things', 'node');
```